# Joining two rows into one row while keeping content

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I'm trying to merge two rows into one row while keeping the content within them. this is my dataset

```
  model DLC  DLC  DLC
0 part  arm  arm  arm
1 coord x    y    probability
```

and this is my target

```
  model     DLC    DLC    DLC
0 position  arm(x) arm(y) arm(prob..)
```

I've tried `.join` and that didn't work. is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to join `coord` row with `part` row:

```
df = df.set_index('model')
df.loc['part'] = df.T.apply(lambda x: '{}({})'.format(x.part, x.coord), axis=1)
df = df.drop(index='coord').reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  model     DLC   DLC.1             DLC.2
0  part  arm(x)  arm(y)  arm(probability)
```